# call app deletegate methods from subclass app delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

So i am new to iOS programming. I am using SDK 4.0 and you know when you build a universal project they provide you with app delegates for the full project and two sub class app delegates classes for iphone and ipad.

Question is how will i call app delegate method from the sub class app delegate class that is extending the app delegate.

Like this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface AppDelegate_iPhone : AppDelegate 
{
   // have to call the AppDelegate methods and its objects.


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send messages to the parent/super class using `super` like `[super doThisMethod];`. If you have to use the ivars or properties declared in the superclass, you can directly refer to them as they were declared in your class - `ivar` or `self.property`.

But you should read [`Apple's guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) on Objective-C first. It is pretty well documented.